# Можете посмотреть, правильность решения

Tags: pascal

Дано натуральное число n. Обчислить S.
Сама задача 1/1*3+1/3*5+...+1/(2n-1)(2n+1)

```
var
    i,n:integer;
    S, k:real;
    begin
    writeln('Vvedit N');
    readln(n);
    i:=1;
    S:=0;
    k:= sqr(n) - sqr(i);
    for i := 1 to n do
    begin
    S:=S+1 / k;
    end;
    writeln('S=', S:8:4);
    readln
    end.
```

Comment: `Сама задача 1/1*3+1/3*5+...+1/(2n-1)(2n+1)` - надо отгадать задачу?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Дано натуральное число n. Обчислить S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Щас я Вам его "обчислю":

```
for i := 1 to n do
begin
  S := S + 1.0 / (4 * i * i - 1);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. У вас условие неправильно записано, как я понимаю.

Должно быть `1/(1*3)+1/(3*5)+...+1/((2n-1)(2n+1))`

2. `sqr(i)` ничего не делает, всегда возвращает 1 в вашем случае.
3. `k:= sqr(n) - sqr(i);` вы посчитали 1 раз перед циклом, а должны считать в цикле, так как оно зависит от `n`. Да и вообще не ясно, зачем это вычисление.

Comment: Вопрос "зачем это вычисление" слишком близко подходит к вопросу о смысле жизни. Не будем его касаться.

Comment: @Suvitruf Дали пример сказали решить, ну я так сказать попытался. Потом понял что, что-то не то решил

Comment: @Suvitruf то есть я так понимаю S:=S+1 / sqr(n) - sqr(i); Где-то так должно всё выглядеть?

Comment: @BraFik Вы понимаете неправильно, выглядеть должно не так, а так, как написал  я.